# pandas how to check the values in a column is sequential

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I like to know how to check the `int/float` values in a column is sequential, e.g. in the following `df`, 2 of 3 columns are considered to have sequential values since their differences are 1;

```
inv_id   ven_id    pay_id
123      1.22      1230
124      2.22      1234
125      3.22      1235
126      4.22      1240
127      5.22      1241
```

`inv_id` and `ven_id` are sequential since the differences between values are all equal 1; `pay_id` is not sequential, since the differences between some of the values are 1.

Comment: df.diff().dropna().eq(1).all()

Answer (score 3):

Based on piRSquared's comment. You should first select only the numeric columns on your df:

`numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
numeric_df = df.select_dtypes(include=numerics)`

Then you should run:

`numeric_df.diff().dropna().eq(1).all()`